# The blinking "|" is appearing out of text boxes

Tags: firefox, accessibility, scrolling

The blinking "|". In my computer, it appears even out of input boxes, so I can't scroll down internet pages normally anymore. I have to wait until it goes to the bottom of the page for the scrolling to start and then when I want to scroll up, I have to wait it goes from the bottom back to the top. What is going on?

Comment: they call it "the cursor" ;-)

Answer (score 11):

In Firefox and IE, press F7 to toggle this.

The behaviour you are describing is "caret browsing".